# NSString not loading double value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm not sure what's going on here. For some reason NSString seems unwilling to load in the double value d.

Here's my code:

```
-(NSString*)minuteFormat:(double) d{
    NSString* mystring;
    if(d >= 10){
        mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", d];
    }else{
        mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",d];
    }
    return(mystring);


}
```

Regardless of the value of d, the only thing that's getting returned is 0 or 00. (And I'm sure d is getting inputted correctly, as I've used breakpoints to check.)

Could someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: `%d` is for decimal **integers**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%d` is for integers.  You probably want `%f`.  See [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

Comment: I feel really, really stupid right now. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is a decimal integer format string. Try `%lf` for double.

Answer (score 0):

You should use %f (double) like this

mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", f];

or do a typecast of the value. For this you may use [yourString floatValue]